# Android multiprocess IPC fail

Tags: android, ipc, multiprocess

Unable to get the `log` from app
This is my code:

------------------AndroidManifest.xml-------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:process=":hello2">
    </activity>
</application>
```

-------------------SecondActivity.java------------

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
protected File mF;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mF = new File(getFilesDir(), "ss");
}

public void write(View view) {
    Storage storage = new Storage("Hello3", 4);

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mF));
        outputStream.writeObject(storage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void read(View view) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(mF));
        Storage storage = (Storage) inputStream.readObject();
        Log.d("Syuu", storage.name);//Error here.no log output
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

--------------------Storage.java----------------

```
public class Storage implements Serializable {
public String name;
public int id;

public Storage(String name, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: My problem is i can't see the log,but I just find I shouldn't choose "Show only selected application" in AndroidStudio. Anyway, thx!